# access php scripts outside www directory

Tags: php

I have a my login details and connect file defined in a folder which is outside www/public. And it works ok. However, I have a got a form and when the user clicks on submit I would the request to be handled by a file in this folder again due to security reasons (which is outside the www folder). However, it tells me access forbidden as if there's an htaccess file (but there isn't such).

```
     <form action="/C:/xampp/login_mysql/process_login.php" method="post"   
     name="login_form">                      
        User: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
        Password: <input type="password" 
                         name="password" 
                         id="password"/>
        <input type="submit" 
               value="Login" /> 
    </form>
```

Comment: action="/C:/" is relative to www directory, so you actually try to use www/public/C:/xampp/login_mysql/process_login.php

Comment: It seems you missed something here... if it is out of your www root, it can't be accessed like that. You store files outside the wwroot specifically for that reason...

Comment: Oh well. I don't want any user to accidentally type in the link of my other php files in the url and access them. I want the user to see only the index.php page

Comment: The users browser can only make requests (GET, POST etc) to public pages. As mentioned in the answer, you need to post to a public page, but include the non public files you need into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` attribute is what the browser gets. You'd need to either

1. move `process_login.php` to a location under the site root, or
2. create a file under the site root to `include` `process_login.php`.

Example for #2:

`<form action="/somewhere/under/the/www/root/process_login.php"`...

and
`somewhere/under/the/www/root/process_login.php`:

```
<?php include 'C:/xampp/login_mysql/process_login.php'; ?>
```